# Parse JSON from a JSON string value

Tags: json, go, struct

I want to convert from string to object.

**From**

```
{"key1": "{\n  \"key2\": \"value2\",\n  \"key3\": {\n    \"key4\": \"value4\"\n  }\n}\n"}
```

**To**

```
{"key1": {"key2": "value2", "key3": {"key4": "value4"}}}
```

Finally, I want to get `value4`.

I can get the value of "key1" using below script.

```
jsondata := `{"key1": "{\n  \"key2\": \"value2\",\n  \"key3\": {\n    \"key4\": \"value4\"\n  }\n}\n"}`
var m map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &m)
value := m["key1"]
fmt.Println(value)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4lwgQJfp5S

But I can't convert the value to an object. So I can't get "value4". Are there methods for this? I can get it by regex like https://play.golang.org/p/6TB-qNAdgQ But now this is not my solution.

Thank you so much for your time and advices. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: @kostix Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two levels of JSON encoding. The first step is to decode the outer JSON value.  Decode to a struct matching the structure of the JSON.

```
var outer struct{ Key1 string }
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &outer); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The next step is to decode the inner JSON value. Again, decode to a struct matching the structure of the JSON.

```
var inner struct{ Key3 struct{ Key4 string } }
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(outer.Key1), &inner); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// The value is inner.Key3.Key4
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/idCSYmudR0)

If the JSON is not double encoded, you can decode in one shot:

```
jsondata := `{"key1": { "key2": "value2",  "key3": { "key4": "value4"  }}}`
var v struct {
    Key1 struct{ Key3 struct{ Key4 string } }
}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &v); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// value is v.Key1.Key3.Key4
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/BAioriddLD)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It worked fine. I couldn't notice to use ``struct``. I accepted your answer as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for adding more knowledge. I want to upvote more. But I had already upvoted. I'm sorry.

Comment: I am sorry. Can I ask you about problems of my question? I want to reflect them to my future questions. BTW, what I want to convert a string JSON to an object using golang is wrong?